# How to access HTML tags loaded on webview and load particular tag on external browser?

Tags: ios

I am loading webview by this method:-

```
NSString *urlString = self.UrlToLoad;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[self.view_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

self.view_webView.delegate=self;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to implement web view delegate method :

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)_webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Now try to detect the url which you want to open in safari browser

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)_webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
      NSString urlLoading = request.URL.absoluteString;
      if ([urlLoading isEqualToString:@"url_that_you_want_to_load"]) {  
      [webView stopLoading];
      //open url in external browser
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
      }
      return YES;
    }
```